# Is Stack Overflow turning into a code-writing resource?

Tags: discussion

After having an account on Stack Overflow for a year or so I've been noticing that every year around the time me and my fellow students head back to college this site gets flooded with homework questions.

The problem I see is that many of my peers aren't spending the time researching and finding resources available online; they come here first and presume that users here (in search of reputation gains) will just complete their code for them. Now, I know that the site is usually good about downvoting these people into oblivion and telling them to do more research on their own before coming here. However, it only takes one person hungry for reputation gain to field their question and give them what they're looking for.

I've seen many of my friends turn in code that they couldn't explain when prompted and fail tests because they found the easy way out by posting here before really putting the time in learning the material.

Is this site becoming a free code-writing resource? In my opinion it is hindering the learning process by giving people an easy way out. Is there a better way to handle situations like this?

Comment: *I've seen many of my friends turn in code that they couldn't explain when prompted and fail tests because they found the easy way out by posting here before really putting the time in learning the material.* **Why is this our problem?**

Comment: Related: [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6166) over on Programmers Meta.

Comment: Kids have been cheating on their homework long before SO ever existed, and they'll be doing it long after SO is dead and gone.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not saying it's necessarily the site's problem. I'm just sharing a trend that I've noticed in school with people coming here and trying to get answers before they really put the time in.

Comment: @Servy I know kids have cheated on their homework and will continue to regardless of what happens here. It's just frustrating seeing people resort to this site without putting any real effort in.

Comment: @BadKarma, but they do fail the tests afterwards, as you say. The system is working.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yes, the system is working. I agree. However, what I'm asking is if there is a better way to handle situations where kids turn here for easy answers. Like an easy way to direct them towards a tutoring resource. Or close the questions before someone can do the work for them?

Comment: To the question if this is a problem: I don't think it is. They will eventually grow up and learn that they do this for themselves, not to make their prof happy. To the question if you can improve something: academia.stackexchange.com maybe?

Comment: @BadKarma: sure, but there isn't anything we can do about students wanting to cheat, nor is it anything new. The site isn't becoming a *quality* code writing service any time soon; anyone needing to rep-hunt-by-homework rather than answer real questions is probably also going to get a large number of things wrong. I don't think there is a trend here either, not over the period of time you mention, I think that's just a [recency illusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recency_illusion).

Comment: @BadKarma: it is impossible to distinguish between motivations for reasonable-effort code problem questions; is it someone trying to do their homework or someone stuck with a problem at work? Bad quality questions get closed anyway. Sure, sometimes they may even get an answer before the post is closed, but their accounts won't evade the question ban for long, nor will their careers last if this is how they treat the profession. It is certainly not our job to protect them from those mistakes.

Comment: @BadKarma: redirecting them to a teaching resource is not going to help here either; these are people that have already made the decision to take the easy way out, what makes you think they will actually read that resource when the professor and learning institute failed to convince them to learn?

Comment: @BadKarma: don't get me wrong, I admire your desire to help out your fellow students, I just don't think there is anything Stack Overflow can do about this. By the time they posted a question here it is *way too late already* to help these souls.

Comment: @BadKarma: as a parent and radical unschooler of my kids, I'd say it is the western school system that is wrong here, where kids are taught to pass tests rather than to develop the natural drive to learn. Changing that is *certainly* outside the scope of what Stack Overflow can achieve.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That is true, the people that have resorted to posting here are not the types who are really interested in what they are studying, but more oft then not people who were forced into compsci by their parents. Even after I've tried to help people who do this and they still post here then have the nerve to brag about it. It's just frustrating is all

Comment: @MartijnPieters I also wholeheartedly agree that the western school system is broken. Test-driven schooling makes people into machines more than having them actually learn. I'm sorry about trying to put this on the site, but I didn't know where else to turn with it

Answer (score 5):

I've answered a couple SQL questions as:

```
select gimmeh_teh_codez
from stackoverflow 
where my_effort is null 
 and thanks = 'given in advance'
```

There's really little that stack moderators can do to limit these and it's in the hands of the community which tends to do a decent job of identifying them, down-vote, and often close (mostly as duplicates, if it's a 'simple' question, it's already been asked and answered on stack).  They are usually basic enough that they are easy to recognize as homework questions.  Especially when the example data they provide is asking you to join the school table to the student table.

My general response is to ask in comments what they have tried so far and atleast get an attempt at a select statement from them.  I will admit, I've face palmed when I saw a question asking how to do a select statement suddenly receive 10 answers from reputation hungry users, but to each their own.  I refuse to up-vote answers to these questions.

Not too surprising to see the seasonal nature of homework questions...I guess the past months have been slow with only summer schoolers asking questions, no?

Comment: You've posted that as an *answer* to these questions? Please don't do that—it might be funny, but it isn't actually an answer. If you find inappropriate questions, please flag them instead.

Comment: @CodyGray - I should clarify these were comments, not answers (if that was my actual answer, I'd flag myself ;)   It's going for a humorous comment way of letting a user know that we're looking for some effort on their part to understand, not just request code.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow is a place to get answers.  Sometimes, the questions come from someone extremely unknowledgeable.  Sometimes the questions seem extremely easy.  I, myself, have asked incredibly n00bish questions over the past few months because my job forced me to switch from Access to C# about 6 months ago without offering any training in the language.  In those instances, mere nudges didn't give me enough information and I had to ask for specific line-by-line code due to my lack of knowledge.

Short of a few fairly obvious tell-tale signs, or the OP explicitly stating it's for homework, it's difficult to know whether the OP is a person in a position such as mine, or a person trying to get an answer by cheating.  I think the SO community does a fairly decent job of making those determinations and closing questions appropriately.  But ultimately, this site is a Q&A resource, and if those questions can be of help to someone else, there's no reason they shouldn't stay on the site.

As for those who come here to cheat, "Cheaters never win, and winners never cheat."  At some point it will bite them for not taking advantage of their education.