# When should we use a custom close reason?

Tags: support, close-reasons

Should we use a custom close reason when there's no correct reason that fits the question (or question fits the reason), or should we use a custom reason because it's better fitted to the question?

For example, assume there's a question **asking for some code**. I think the question could be closed as **too broad**, but in some cases I will encounter another user using a custom close reason such as :

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO isn't a code writing service.

Is this reason better than **too broad**?

**Related:** [The custom close reasons which start with "I'm voting to close [...]"](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/421428/537400/the-custom-close-reasons-which-start-with-im-voting-to-close).

Comment: Hey, Kevin. The first paragraph seemed a bit hard to understand and I tried editing it, I hope I didn't alter the meaning of what you were trying to say.

Comment: @Jim: Oh, your edit is good. Thanks :D

Comment: Use it when you have something *constructive* to say, anything that helps the OP decide how to progress.  It is not very suitable for "get lost" messages like your example, Too Broad is already plenty good enough.  People do get put in the slammer for snarky custom messages like this

Comment: @HansPassant: Ah, so that means: *The reason is to OP, not to the question.* We need choose a clear reason for OP to let him easy understand *what's the problem of the question*. And if there's no already exists one, then use a custom reason right?

Comment: @KevinGuan a clear reason to an OP that may be willing to make an effort to use the info correctly.  If you think the OP is just going to ignore the feedback, then it is a waste of effort.

Comment: @psubsee2003: Oh yeah, makes sense.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Funny thing, you don't always know how the OP is going to react. [Example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ojemo.png) of a strange response particularly from a user with more than 500 rep. I will continue to use those custom close reasons, because they have *some* guidance. Custom close reasons are particularly useful when there are (small) sites that are much better suited for specific questions.

Comment: As far as I remember the written close reason isn't available anymore, when the question was closed. One can then only see the rather generic "doesn't match criteria". So it is less helpful at that point.

Comment: @Tom I'm pretty sure the custom close reason sticks around after the question is closed.

Comment: @TinyGiant It appears that the custom close reason isn't displayed after the question is closed (although [it happens to still be visible in the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34711773/4151918)).

Comment: @Petah That's what I meant. Some people put some pretty obnoxious and rude things in those comments, so I'm very glad it isn't displayed in a notice on the question itself. You cannot flag a notice is rude.

Comment: @TinyGiant: Huh, I think we still can raise a mod flag right? For example, when we start a bounty, we can put something in that notice box, and they maybe can be rude, then a mod flag is needed.

Comment: Yeah, I guess. Even so, featuring those comments in a notice on the question would be problematic at best.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The custom close reason is a sub-reason of off-topic.

You'll use it if none of the other pre-baked off-topic reasons or migration targets can explain why the question doesn't fit on Stack Overflow.

Remember that closing means that the question can't or shouldn't be answered in its current form. It needs to be improved by the OP or deleted.

If we assume we don't want to risk losing a potential good question, the custom close reason should give the OP enough guidance to either edit their question into shape or decide to delete it all together.

When you are a regular on a different site that is not a migration target you can suggest to see if the question fits on another site in the SE network.

For the licensing/legal related questions there are some custom reasons around mainly because legal stuff somehow is related to programming but we prefer to keep that off-topic.

In that respect

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO isn't a code writing service.

isn't good use of the custom close reason. Either 'Unclear' or 'Too Broad' are better in these cases. Both close reasons have links to the Help center in their close notice, so that should help the OP determine why their question was closed.

Telling what Stack Overflow isn't can be a long list. If you use comments or a custom close reason make sure they are respectful to the OP ([be nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240839/the-new-new-be-nice-policy-code-of-conduct-updated-with-your-feedback)) and explain what Stack Overflow is. That is hard enough.

Comment: Sometimes there are clear and well defined questions asking for code. Then you either have to use the mentioned custom reason or not closing at all. Just using another pre-defined close reason which does not apply would be even more confusing.

Comment: The mentioned custom reason shouldn't be used in that form, ever @Trilarion. Just expand it to explain that you need the current attempt, where they are stuck, what they have tried and where they need exactly help with. In the form as mentioned in the question the comment is rude, IMHO.

Comment: Okay than what I mean is that not only 'unclear' or 'too broad' are alternatives in these cases. Another alternative could be then not to close vote at all? See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215596/are-code-questions-without-an-attempt-now-on-topic, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310104/code-writing-questions-what-is-the-proper-flag-to-use, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260951/on-what-grounds-should-a-question-asking-blindly-for-code-be-closed, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270196/is-stackoverflow-turning-into-a-code-writing-resource

Comment: @Trilarion sure, if you decide not to close vote at all this question and the answer are not needed. And the other answers you link to clearly extend the custom close reason.